# How can I run calculations on batches of entries in a table based on other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2022

I have a SQL table that looks kind of like the following

```
entry_ID    type_of_entry   time_of_entry
1           0               12:00
2           0               12:05
3           1               12:15
4           0               15:14
5           1               15:30
```

What I'm hoping to do is extract the times taken between the first 0 in the type of entry chain, and the 1 to end the chain. The number of 0 type_of_entry rows between the 1s will vary.

So for this table I would want:

```
TIMEDIFF(12:15 , 12:00) = 15 mins
TIMEDIFF(15:30 , 15:14) = 16 mins
```

How can I get the groupings I want, ideally without looping through the table with a FOR EACH?

Comment: SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) doesn't work with MySQL, so why have you tagged both?

Comment: My bad, it's definitely SSMS.  SQL Server 16.0

Comment: Then you should tag SQL Server, not SSMS; SSMS is just an IDE like environment so tagging it for your (R)DBMS is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language. As you're using SQL Server 16, you should tag [[tag:sql-server-2022]] too when you correct the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you have here is a gaps and islands problem. One method to put the data into groups is to use `COUNT` to count the number of `1` entries *prior* to the current row. Then you can get the difference in minutes for the `MAX` and `MIN` entry times in each of those groups:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT entry_ID,
           type_of_entry,
           time_of_entry,
           COUNT(CASE type_of_entry WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY entry_ID 
                                                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp
    FROM (VALUES(1,0,CONVERT(time(0),'12:00:00')),
                (2,0,CONVERT(time(0),'12:05:00')),
                (3,1,CONVERT(time(0),'12:15:00')),
                (4,0,CONVERT(time(0),'15:14:00')),
                (5,1,CONVERT(time(0),'15:30:00')))V(entry_ID,type_of_entry,time_of_entry))
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(time_of_entry), MAX(time_of_entry)) AS TimeDiff
FROM Grps
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY MIN(entry_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gap and island problem, we need to group the data in such a way that every two successive rows belong to the same group. This can be achieved by using the window function `sum()`, once the data is grouped, apply the datediff function to calculate the time difference between consecutive rows within each group :

The first cte is used to establish an initial grouping of the data.

The second cte2, is used to identify the first occurrence of type 0 and the last occurrence of type 1.

cte3 is used to generate the final grouping based on the previous CTEs.

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(type_of_entry) over (order by entry_ID ) as rn
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select type_of_entry, min(entry_ID) as entry_ID
  from cte 
  where type_of_entry = 0
  group by type_of_entry, rn
  union all
  select type_of_entry, max(entry_ID) as entry_ID
  from cte 
  where type_of_entry = 1
  group by type_of_entry, rn
),
cte3 as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by entry_ID) as rn
  from cte2
)
select DATEDIFF(minute, CONVERT(TIME, min(time_of_entry)), CONVERT(TIME, max(time_of_entry)))
from cte3 c
inner join mytable t on t.entry_ID = c.entry_ID
group by floor((rn-1)/2)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UtNacZxS)